# Intuitionism, the law of excluded middle and mental construct

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I don't get why LEM is rejected in intuitionistic logic. The basic idea behind intuitionism is that math is a mental construct. But how does this make LEM not acceptable? I've seen some similar posts but I still don't quite get this. To me the relationship between LEM and mental construction is not so obvious.

Comment: The basic idea is that in intuitionism, mathematical propositions hold if human beings have the mental capacity to prove them. There is no truth beyond what is provable, unlike in mathematical platonism. But there are pairs of propositions P, ¬P such that neither is provable. So if truth is provability, then neither is true. Hence bivalence fails to hold.

Comment: "there are pairs of propositions P, ¬P such that neither is provable" holds in non-intuitionistic mathematics too. The requirement for a proof (or an axiom) also holds in standard mathematics.

Comment: @Frank hmm if so then what makes intuitionism and LEM incompatible

Comment: @Irene isn't it that intuitionism shuns non-constructive proofs by contradiction, which rest on the LEM?

Comment: To assert that there are either finitely or infinitely many perfect numbers constructively, you must either construct the largest perfect number, or give an algorithm that constructs a larger perfect number for any given one. Neither construction may exist. Therefore, LEM is constructively false, see [SEP, Rejection of *Tertium Non Datur*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#RejeTertNonDatu).

Comment: That there are pairs of propositions P, ¬P such that neither is provable holds in classical mathematics, but the platonist has the option of saying that one or other is true, but not provable. For the intuitionist, truth and provability stand or fall together. If neither is provable, neither is true, hence bivalence does not hold for the intuitionist.